# Should I use a factory pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I currently have a class named ConfigProfile factory and it contains methods for say a default profile, current settings, ect. This class gets used internally by my Profile service. I was thinking that it would be better to simply make this a true factory and just create the appropriate Profile Service for each of the products we are configuring.

```
    public string GetDefaultProfile(string product)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(product))
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("product");
        }

        string profile = null;

        if (product.Contains("Product 1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) ||
            product.Contains("product1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            profile = Resources.product1DefaultProfile;
        }

        return profile;
    }
```

that is only one product there, but we have several more which means I will have to add more if statements for each one. The profile service already has an interface and is what gets used for most of my program. Also there are several methods that use this same way of doing things. So would a factory that returns the appropriate profile service based on product name be a better solution or is there something else I could do?

Edit: This is one of the simpler methods in this class. the more complex one is the one that retrieves the current system settings from the required places. Like all products have IIS settings, but some will have theme support while others will have database configuration to do.

Comment: I'd have a map where the name is the key and the value is the profile.  How does profile differ by product?  Sounds like it could be one that acts the same for all products.  I don't see the need for a factory.

Comment: It could be the same it will just have different sections. Like the first product we did just deals with IIS and the web.config, but for another product it will be the same except add in themes and database stuff. Each of those sections has their own service to set them up eg IIS has its own service class that applies the settings and reads the current settings.

Comment: Just a note: your method can throw an `ArgumentNullException` when the argument is not null, merely empty. If an empty non-null argument should never be passed in, then you should throw an `ArgumentException`.

Comment: @ThomSmith Ok I will change that. I intend for the exception to be thrown on null and empty as it should never be either.

Comment: Strategy pattern is the best solution for your example. If I have an IOC container like UnityContainer,i would register the class with the product name so that i can resolve it using that product name.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try that because I have been wanting to use an IOC container anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factory is a very good solution. It allows you to hide the configuration complexity behind a simple interface.

If you need to be able to configure it at run-time/start-up, combine with Strategy.

Both solutions - static factory or Strategy - can be combined with Prototype. Prototype would be useful as an optimization, if you often use the same profile, and it's read-only.

EDIT: You are probably using Prototype already. Your sample code looks like you are copying/referencing a profile rather than building it as a complex product.

Comment: For that default profile I am just referencing a static xml document in the resources, but for current settings I build a complex object. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Why thank you for your follow-up. Always nice to learn more about the issue :)